# Would the verb in this sentence be used transitively or intransitively?

Tags: grammar, verbs, transitive-verbs, intransitive-verbs

In the following sentence is "painted" being used transitively or intransitively?

> The sunset painted the sky with a tapestry of fiery colors.

I asked ChatGPT about this and it gives reasons for both...

For intransitive that it's being used metaphorically or poetically; the focus is on the action of sunset creating a visual effect, not the application of paint.

When I reminded it that "the sky" certainly seemed to be the direct object it agreed at first that it was actually transitive. Yet when asked to confirm, it stated it was intransitive. Then it finally stated it's a matter of interpretation.

Personally, I think it's transitive. Am I right?

Comment: Yes, it's metaphoric and still transitive. They painted the wall with bright colors.

Comment: I've found that if you challenge a ChatGPT answer it sometimes apologizes too quickly.

Comment: ChatGPT dishes up a lot of shite.

Answer (score 3):

I wouldn't rely on ChatGPT for this sort of thing. You are correct that "paint" here is transitive.

Sometimes people make the mistake of saying that a direct object must somehow "receive" an action or "be acted on" by the subject. This is incorrect; a transitive verb is one that takes a direct object, regardless of its semantic role.

Comment: Somewhat circular. Allerton, in _The Handbook of English Linguistics_ (eds Aarts and McMahon) claims that post-verb noun groups such as appear in

• _The piano resembled a pianola._

• _The piano weighed a ton._

• _The piano had a stool._

• _The piano seemed an antique._

should not be considered objects but are 'best regarded as belonging to a slightly different category'. And sentences like 'Have you eaten?' are described by some as containing pseudo-transitive usages. But I wouldn't have thought (till now) that anyone would interpret 'painted the sky ...' as intransitive.